# Usual Arithmetic Conversions

Tags: types, integer

[In here (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09ka8bxx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) I've read about uac and everything is well and fine but last rule is bit disturbing. If I have two operands of type `unsigned short` will they be converted to `int` not to `unsiged int`?

Comment: *"I've read about uac..."* What do you mean by "UAC" here? I assume you're not talking about [User Account Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control), right? Because I can't imagine that would have anything at all to do with type conversion.

Comment: he means uac = Usual Arithmetic Conversions

Answer (score 1):

Thins might have something to do with chains of conversions. Although you don't need the int to be signed, it isn't harmful to use a signed int, either. SO in principle, both options should work.

By using the "normal" / signed int, you end up with a less restrictive case for further conversion.